# Haskell Integer and Int types; conversion not working

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to solve Project Euler problem 59, where I have to xor-decrypt a message that has a three-character key (all lowercase). In ASCII this would mean the set of all keys is

```
let keys = [[a, b, c] | a <- [97..122], b <- [97..122], c <- [97..122]]
```

and the following functions would together heuristically decrypt it:

```
decrypt :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Char]
decrypt msg xs = map chr $ zipWith xor msg $ (concat . repeat) xs

try :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [Char]
try kys msg = head $ filter (isInfixOf "the") $ map (decrypt msg) kys
```

where basically I keep on trying keys until one of them decrypts the message to have a "the" in it (I know the message has common English words). But when I bind `keys` and `message` and run `try keys message` I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    Expected type: [[Int]]
      Actual type: [[Integer]]
    In the first argument of `try', namely `keys'
    In the expression: try keys message
```

Now, even when I say `let keys = [map fromIntegral [a, b, c] | a <- [97..122], b <- 97..122],, c <- [97..122]]` it still says it has type `Integer` and not `Int` and also when I try `let keys = map (map fromIntegral) keys`, and also when I use `fromInteger`. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `keys` defaults to `[[Integer]]`. Override this by adding a type annotation when defining `keys`:

```
let keys = ... :: [[Int]]
```

This is because the type of numeric literals (and the return type of `fromIntegral`) is polymorphic, so when you write `let keys = ...` the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) kicks in and defaults the numeric types to `Integer` unless they're constrained in some other way.

```
> let x = 42 
> :t x
x :: Integer
> let y = 42 :: Int
> :t y
y :: Int
```

Another solution is to disable the monomorphism restriction. Then `keys` will be a polymorphic value which will be specialized to `[[Int]]` when you try to use it.

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let x = 42
> :t x
x :: Num b => b
```

Comment: If someone were to read this question in the future note that `let keys = [[a, b, c] | a <- map fromIntegral [97..122] :: [Int], b <- map fromIntegral [97..122] :: [Int], c <- map fromIntegral [97..122] :: [Int]]` was the precise code that fixed it. Also, thanks hammar, I wasn't aware of this form of typecasting.

Comment: @jclancy If you specify a type of `Int` for (at least) one of the literals, or `[Int]` for (at least) one of the `[97 .. 122]` lists, or `[[Int]]` for `keys`, you don't need any `fromIntegral`.

Comment: Ah, for some reason that didn't work for me before, maybe a typo. Then the best solution is `let keys = [[a, b, c] | a <- [97..122], b <- [97..122], c <- [97..122]] :: [[Int]]`